# Gradient descent for more than 2 theta values

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Gradient descent algorithm is given as :

[image]

(taken from Andres NG coursera course)
How should this algorithm be implemented if there are more than 2 theta parameters (feature weights) ?

Should an extra theta value be included :

[image]

and repeat until convergence, in other words, until theta0, theta1, theta2 no longer change ?

Comment: Hand drawn boxes and partial derivatives. cool!

Comment: Maybe convert theta to matrix notation then big theta = big theta - alpha/m * sigma(h(big theta(X) - Y)  * X .   Andrew Ng's notation is to make it clear to those less comfortable with matrix notation - which i doubt includes yourself.

Comment: @javadba thanks, "big theta = big theta - alpha/m * sigma(h(big theta(X) - Y) * X" should be "big theta = big theta - alpha(1//m) * sigma(h(big theta(X) - Y) * X" ? you ommited 1/m ?

Comment: yes.  (plus some filler here  to get to min comment length ;) )

Comment: @javadba I think what confused me is that GD should be used within loop so that all thetas are updated simultaneously, but same is true for matrix multiplication

Comment: Actually the matrix formulation - a single equation instead of many ones - is more clear: it states that effectively the update is an atomic operation across all vectors in the design matrix. It is the responsibility of the underlying linear algebra library to make that "happen" .

Comment: @javadba yes, thanks for clarifying. feel free to put into answer and I'll accept .

Comment: I don't know how to format the answer properly.. looking into it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe convert theta to matrix notation then

```
 big theta = big theta - alpha/m * sigma(h(big theta(X) - Y) * X .
```

Andrew Ng's notation is to make it clear to those less comfortable with matrix notation - which i doubt includes yourself. –

The matrix formulation - a single equation instead of many ones - may be more clear than the serially/individually depicted equations from the OP.  The single matrix formulation shows that  effectively the update is an atomic operation across all vectors in the design matrix. It is the responsibility of the underlying linear algebra library to make that "happen" .